# How to update the original list with another list from a for-loop in a recursion in Python

Tags: python, list, recursion, for-loop

Let's say I have a list, `L = [a,b,c,d]`, and a copy of this list, and also a for-loop that has a recursion code in it:

```
    for item in L:
        if:
            *some base code*
            Lcopy.remove(item)
            L = []
            L += Lcopy[:]
        else:
            *some recursion code*
    return ...
```

But after the every recursion is done, L goes back to how it was originally. I know that once the code goes into the recursion, Python gives a new memory address to the list (L) that it uses, but is it possible to make the original L, the very first L, to update and get rid of the values that was was supposed to be deleted?

Comment: i have no idea what you're asking and suspect you might be confusing some terms.  what output do you want here?

Comment: Why are you copying Lcopy again? That is an unnecessary expensive operation; since `+=` operator doesn't change its RHS argument.

Comment: Well... the output is actually a tree. I just need the original list to delete the item that I went through already in the recursion. :S

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `L = []`

This is the moment after `L` is pointing to another value, a newly created list.

Python doesn't do anything special with references in recursion. Lists are always passed by reference. Assignment breaks the reference of `L` to the old list.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `L = []` you're re-assigning that function's local name `L` to a completely new list. If you instead want to empty out the same list, you need to delete all of its contents, like so: `del L[:]`

For a more detailed explanation of Python's execution model, and what assigning to a variable actually does, check out [this blog post by Jeff Knupp](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model).